# Linker error when linking C++ code with USB driver (ftdi)

Tags: c++, usb, driver, ftdi

I am on a Mac OSX and I am trying to start using the C ftdi drivers I installed using brew

```
brew install libftdi
```

That installed the library in the directory `/usr/local/Cellar/libftdi/1.2` And I have the following C++ code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ftdi.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    struct ftdi_context ftdi;
    ftdi_init(&ftdi);

    cout << "Hello World" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

How should I compile this to make it work?  I am including the `include/` directory so the compiler can find the header file but I do not know which object file should be linked.  I am trying to using the following command

```
g++ -I /usr/local/Cellar/libftdi/1.2/include/libftdi1/ /usr/local/Cellar/libftdi/1.2/lib/libftdi1.a test.cpp
```

But I am getting bad linker errors even though I have included the `.a` file.  The `lib/` directory has the following contents

```
cmake
libftdi1.2.2.0.dylib
libftdi1.2.dylib -> libftdi1.2.2.0.dylib
libftdi1.a
libftdi1.dylib -> libftdi1.2.dylib
pkgconfig
```

Is there something else I should try and link it to? Even if you are not aware of this particular driver is there something in general that I should be doing for drivers like this that I have not done?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: That was a mistake.  I should have written `g++`

Comment: What you have done is OK so far, IMHO. But there's one thing you seem to overlook: libftdi **needs** libusb!

Comment: @tofro Where is libusb?

Comment: @tofro I found it but I still get more linker error originating from `libusb`, for example undefined `_CFGetTypeID`

Comment: Probably close to where you found libftdi. Or on sourceforge, if all else fails.

Comment: @tofro I found it!  I am still getting more bugs though.  I think I need to link the functions in libusb to something else as well that I am not very aware of right now

Comment: Try something along the lines of `g++ -I /usr/local/Cellar/libftdi/1.2/include/libftdi1/ -L /usr/local/Cellar/libftdi/1.2/lib -l ftdi1 test.cpp`. `-L` look here for libraries. `-l` link this library.

Comment: I was able to get this to work `g++ -I /usr/local/Cellar/libftdi/1.2/include/libftdi1/ /usr/local/Cellar/libftdi/1.2/lib/libftdi1.a -L/usr/local/lib -lusb-1.0 test.cpp` I am not sure why though. Could someone please explain the `-L` flag?

Comment: -L: "Look for libraries that are specified with -l<library file name stripped off the "lib"> in the following directory.". It is needed to make the "-lusb-1.0" part work.

Comment: @tofro does it look for .so/.dylib files? .a files?  Also how does the compiler know when to look for a dynamically linked library?  Does that not break the abstraction between the compiler and the operating system? Because that would mean that the object file contains a call to the dynamic linker right?

Comment: If you really want to know what you have done, try `otool -L <your binary>`. This should give you all the dynamic libraries that you linked your binary against. What doesn't show up here, but was on your linker command line, is linked statically.

Comment: @tofro You could write your answer in the form of an answer.

Comment: @AlanStokes I'm still curious about what exactly the `-L` flag is doing though.  Could you post a bare bones example that generates a dylib file and then use the -L flag to link against this?